# BehaviorSubject observe multiple values for Angular 2

Tags: angular, observable, behaviorsubject

I am trying to use behavior subject and observable in Angular2 to pass in 3 parameters in one array.

```
BehaviorSubject<Array<Something1>, Array<Something2>, Array<Something3>>
```

This doesn't seem to work because behavior subject only support one parameter. Any suggestions?

Comment: you're not passing any parameters there, you're just specifying the type

Comment: is there anything unclear about [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45430478/2545680)?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass an array of arrays. Just surround it with [];

```
BehaviorSubject<[Array<Something1>, Array<Something2>, Array<Something3>]>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you write like this:

```
BehaviorSubject<Array<Something1>, Array<Something2>, Array<Something3>>
```

You're not passing any parameters. You're merely specifying what types this subject will be emitting. To specify that it can produce items of three different types use the `|` operator which is the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types):

```
class T1 {}
class T2 {}
class T3 {}

const o = [new T1()];
const s = new BehaviorSubject<Array<T1> | Array<T2> | Array<T3>>(o);
```

Also, `BehaviorSubject` takes one value. Here is description [from the docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject):

> One of the variants of Subjects is the BehaviorSubject, which has a
>   notion of "the current value". It stores the latest value emitted to
>   its consumers, and whenever a new Observer subscribes, it will
>   immediately receive the "current value" from the BehaviorSubject.

So when you instantiate a `BehaviorSubject` you have to pass that one "current" value. That is why only one parameter is expected because there's only one "current" value. And this value can be of any of the types you specify between the `<...>` when instantiating a subject.